# .htaccess redirect file type

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, file-type

I have some old `.swf` files/links for a website and they currently lead to a `404 Not Found` page.
I was wondering if there was a simple way, using `.htaccess` (or any other method you may recommend) to redirect these files/links to my websites homepage `http:www.mysite.com/home`.

Example links:

`http://www.mysite.com/folder/file.swf`

`http://www.mysite.com/file.swf`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.*\.swf$ /home [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com/(.*).swf$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect all your swf files to www.mysite.com/home permanently you can do it with an .htaccess file.

First of all, you'll have to enable mod_rewrite in apache.

Then add the following to your .htaccess file :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^mysite\.com/(.*).swf$ http://www\.mysite\.com/home [R=301,NC,L]
```