# How can I know which static pages on my site are being visited?

Tags: php, apache, analytics

How can I know which static pages on my site are being visited?
By static pages I mean PDF for the most part.

I use Apache and PHP.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about a programming problem. For help finding your log files, you might be better off with https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This may involve making configurations in Apache

Comment: Still not a programming problem.

Comment: in case you have cpanel / vhm you can see the visitor sections if you can access logs by limitations . some had filters and you can put the name of pdf of partial ..i would try  ".pdf"   so to see all pdf accessed ,in case are many

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Constantin I need to create a system to analyze which pages are being visited, I don't use Cpanel, anyway the system will have to record the visits in a database and then display it to the site administrators.
I just don't know how to capture hits in PDF files, I think there may be a solution using apache/htaccess and PHP, but I'm not sure how to do that.
I just need some direction on how this can be done.
I'm thinking of doing as a friend suggested, which is to get apache acesslog access, but i am not sure if it is the best approach

Comment: Hi @zidniryi
I have no code yet.
I just need some guidance on how that can be done

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your apache config. It will specify the location of logfiles that you want to look at.

I believe the default location is `/var/log/apache2` once there you can monitor traffic in real time with something like `tail -f access.log` or you can process the logfiles to get an idea of how many hits the resources are getting.

Comment: That will help. Thanks.
What happens when access.log gets too big? they are excluded?

Comment: I use nginx so I am not sure, but look in that folder and there should be some kind of log rotation happening automagically. Check the manual! https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

Answer (score 0):

assuming you had in xampp (preferable windows cause for sure cmod write right are on) the folder 0 and you can access http://localhost/0/ cause the server is on ,

assuming you use links like this to acces each pdf file:

http://localhost/0/file1.pdf

http://localhost/0/file2.pdf

assuming your php.ini settings does allow to run error_log function

you have these files
**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /0/
RewriteRule ^.*\.pdf$ ?countfile=$0 [R=301,L,QSA]

# i'm not so pro with .htaccess so i used work based on
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949685/htaccess-redirect-file-type
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439192/rewrite-url-relative-to-current-directory
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    isset($_REQUEST['countfile'])and error_log($_REQUEST['countfile']."\r\n",3,'logpdf.txt');
    header('');
    //include($_REQUEST['countfile']);
    header("Content-type:application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename='".$_REQUEST['countfile']);
    readfile($_REQUEST['countfile']);
?>
```

**results.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="CustaRoolez">
<title>just for fun</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(file_exists('logpdf.txt')){
    $files=file('logpdf.txt');
    $statistics=array_count_values($files);
    foreach($statistics as $file => $cnt){
        echo 'the file: '.$file.' was accesed by'.$cnt.' times<br>';
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

then should be the fastest custom method to logs visits statistics to count pdf access files

on https://www.real-domain-whaterver.extension
.htaccess may be like this (you should set the route ,isn't automaticly)
so for `https://www.real-domain-whaterver.extension/  <---- '/'` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*\.pdf$ ?countfile=$0 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

remember you should have right to write so on real public domain you could modify
in **index.php**

```
error_log($_REQUEST['countfile']."\r\n",3,'logpdf.txt');
```

to

```
error_log($_REQUEST['countfile']."\r\n",3,'/someFOLDERtoLOG/logpdf.txt');
```

---

and **results.php**

```
if(file_exists('logpdf.txt')){
    $files=file('logpdf.txt');
```

to

```
if(file_exists('/someFOLDERtoLOG/logpdf.txt')){
    $files=file('/someFOLDERtoLOG/logpdf.txt');
```

and sure create someFOLDERtoLOG and setting cmod 775 or verify if is already(depend by administrator settings)